# AngularJS multiple $watch cause multiple requests on controller initialization

Tags: angularjs, watch

Consider the following code;

```
function ListCtrl($scope){

  this.fetchResults = function(){};

  // so I can pass this as a reference & spyOn fetchResults
  function fetchResults = function(){return this.fetchResults()}.bind(this);

  $scope.page = 1;
  $scope.order = null;

  $scope.$watch('page',fetchResults);
  $scope.$watch('order',fetchResults);

  this.fetchResults();

}
```

I want to write this code in this manner, so I can test if each watch triggers the `fetchResults`. But this way, **when `ListCtrl` is initalized, it calls `fetchResults` 3 times**

1. explicitly called
2. for `$watch('page')`
3. for `$watch('order')`

What can I do to make the `ListCtrl` call `fetchResults` only once on initialization ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [$scope.$watch docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch):

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.

So you can do something like this:

```js
function watchFetchResults(newValue, oldValue) {
  if(newValue !== oldValue){
    fetchResults();
  }
}

$scope.$watch('page',watchFetchResults);
$scope.$watch('order',watchFetchResults);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
$scope.$watch('page + order', fetch);
```

This would watch both expressions at once, simply concatenating them in an angular expression.

Comment: if `page` and `order` changes value in the same $digest cykel, this watcher might not get called (e.g if `page = 1` and `order = 0` and their values changes to `page = 0` and `order = 1`)

Comment: You could do something like `$scope.$watch("page + '~' + order")` to make it a string, then.

Comment: Yeah, but this isn't fool proof either (page = '', order = '~' => page = '~', order ='') - maybe you know that page and order will always be integers and that will never happend - but still the code ends up beeing a bit more confusing. Just a matter of taste I guess :)

Comment: This code is more efficient, since it only sets up one $watch.  $watches are things you want to setup as little as possible.  It is a matter of taste, but also of efficiency in this case :-)